# How to get the values between current date and current date of previous year in sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to get the data from sqlite database between current date one year before. I used the following code. But it didn't provide the data. Consider the current date is 25-10-2013. There is data for 25-09-2013. But the code inside do, doesn't execute. I don't get what is wrong in the code. The same way, I used for 3 months before and 6 months before, they work fine.

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar cal11 =Calendar.getInstance();
    cal11.add(Calendar.MONTH, -12);
    String  one_year_before = cur_format1111.format(cal11.getTime());
    Log.v("one_year_before", one_year_before);
```

**Query to select data:**

```
 Cursor cur21 = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TIMER_TABLE
                        + " WHERE  cur_date BETWEEN ?  AND ?", new String[] {
                        one_year_before, cur_form_Date });
if (cur21 != null) {
                if (cur21.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        has_valuesyear = true;
                        String reader_name_db_service = cur21.getString(cur21
                                .getColumnIndex("username"));
                        Log.v("reader_name_db_service21",
                                reader_name_db_service);
                        if (reader_name_db
                                .equalsIgnoreCase(reader_name_db_service)) {
                            String tot_reading_time = cur21.getString(cur21
                                    .getColumnIndex("tot_reading"));
                            Log.v("tot_reading_time21", tot_reading_time);
                            String cur_date = cur21.getString(cur21
                                    .getColumnIndex("cur_date"));
                            Log.v("cur_date21", cur_date);
                            one_year_set.add(reader_name_db_service + "~"
                                    + cur_date + "~" + tot_reading_time);

                        }

                    } while (cur21.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            cur21.close();
            db.close();
```

Comment: What is `format1111`?

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You would first have to store your dates as character in **ISO format**.  Then your query will work.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe give this a shot

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, String[] {"column1", "column2"}, "cur_date BETWEEN " + year_before + " AND " + year_after +";",null,null,null,null,null);
```

The string array of columns, in your case, will contain all of your columns. The last `null`'s are for ordering and limits.

Comment: -1: Doesn't answer question and also ignore good practice of using parameters!